# Delphi XE 7 Indy IRC detect connection lost

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy, delphi-xe7

All works good but sometimes after many hours connection can be lost. How i should detect that chat isnt workin anymore? Should i use PING/PONG event to detect that? This happens very rare, but still can happen. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Er, which Delphi version you're using? Have you read the RFC (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2812#section-3.7.2)?

Comment: You should `PING` your server periodically, but this is totally unrelated to Delphi.

Comment: Im using Delphi XE 7

Comment: @mjn, this is not true. 100% of servers I've seen in the wild were complying to protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the IRC PING and PONG commands should be used to improve connection stability.

---

Server and client could send "empty" (no-op, heart-beat) messages to keep the connecion alive. If one party does not receive these messages anymore, the connection can be considered lost. The server then can simply close the connection, if he detects an unresponsive client. A client could display an error message and offer the user to connect again, or re-connect automatically.

Adding no-op (heart-beat) messages alone will help to keep a connection stable, as some network components may chose to terminate connections after long time of inactivity.

Comment: Ugh... Isnt that a purpose of `PING`? Please consider reading protocol specs.

Comment: @FreeConsulting sorry for the misunderstanding, edited